# Is it possible to set custom status message (in utf-8) in http status header?

Tags: php, apache, http

I want to change http status header with my own status message. For example, change `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` to `HTTP/1.1 200 custom status message in utf-8`. To do it, I send some headers with php:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
HTTP/1.1 200 custom status message in utf-8
```

But in Chrome developer tools I see status message in wrong encoding, for example `Status Code:200 Ð£Ð¿Ñ! Ð§ÑÐ¾-ÑÐ¾`. Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) the encoding is undefined, so it's not worth trying non-ASCII, furthermore, (b) the reason phrase does not exist anymore in in HTTP/2.

Comment: Ok, the encoding is define in Content-type header. So, can I use my own phrase in other language (differ from English)? If not, can you explain why?

Comment: No, Content-Type defines the payload of the HTTP message, not anything in the headers. I can't explain why it was left undefined, but it is.

Comment: This answer currently misses the sources for the statements. It would be good to have references to the relevant parts of the specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You just used below line to change HTTP header status code and messages

```
$msg = "custom status message";

header("Status: 200");
header("HTTP/1.1 200 ".$msg);
```

Comment: I mean status message in language, different from English (for example in Greek or Russian).